# for loop and a function combined to calculate a formula and then a regression

Tags: r, function, loops

A little confused with how I am trying to acheive the results I want.

I have an environment in R which consists of 5 data.frames called `df[i]`

So;

```
df1
df2
df3
df4
df5
```

Inside of these `df´s` I have 5 columns called `col[j]`

```
col1
col2
col3
col4
col5
```

In total I have 25 columns across 5 data frames (5 df x 5 col).

I also have a static variable called `R` which is a vector of numbers

I am trying to calculate for each column of each dataframe a basic formula using a function/loop. The formula for column 1 of df1 would be;

```
Y = df1$col1 - R
```

I am trying to calculate this and repeat for each `colum[j:5]` in `df[i:5]` and store it in a new `data.frame`

```
j <- 1:5
i <- 1:5
fun <- function(x){
  for(i in 1:col[j](df[i])){
    Y[j] <- col[j] - R
  }
}
```

EDIT: Added comment below for easier reading.

```
Y1a = df1$col1 - R
Y2a = df1$col2 - R
Y3a = df1$col3 - R  
..... 

.....
 Y1b = df2$col1 - R 
 Y2b = df2$col2 - R 
 Y3b = df2$col3 - R
..... etc
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want to do. A good start would be using `dplyr::mutate_each(df1, function(x) x - R)`

Comment: Okay, so I want to calculate the formula `Y = df[i]$col[j] - R` across all 5 dataframes and all columns, for example;

`Y1a = df1$col1 - R` | `Y2a = df1$col2 - R`  | `Y3a = df1$col3 - R`  ..... and .... `Y1b = df2$col1 - R` | `Y2b = df2$col2 - R` | `Y3b = df2$col3`.... etc

Comment: Do you really want a for loop or this is what you've tried so far? What @Flo.P suggested is one of the ways to do it, but you have to apply that process to each of your datasets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Put your data in a list:    
dflist = mget(paste0("df", 1:5))

# Apply your function to every data frame
ylist = lapply(dflist, function(x) x - R)

# Name the resulting columns y1:y5
ylist = lapply(ylist, setNames, paste0("y", 1:5))
```

Have a look at [How to make a list of data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207) for examples and discussion of why using lists is better.

Answer (score 1):

**tidyverse version**

`dplyr::mutate_all` apply a fonction to each column of a data.frame.

So I would do like that:

```
all_df <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5) 
map(all_df, function(x) mutate_all(x, function(y) y - R))
```

It should return you a list of length 5. Each df contains your desired statistic.